# Why does my Visual Studio 2015 Community sometimes hangs while building solution, is type of problems exists for Enterprise edition too?

Tags: android, xamarin

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar.Hide();
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyActivityLayout);
    }
```

When I clean and rebuild, I am facing the same problem i.e: it is not displaying the files that are added in the layout folder, not able to access control id's from IntelliSense.

Comment: Your title is not related to what you are asking in your post. Could you please modify the question so that the title and content are referring to the same problem?

Comment: And to reproduce the problem, could you please offer some screenshots or description about your project structure?